# automatic test tool for .net

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing

I am **really** new to unit tests and I don't know if my question is actually relevent to unit tests - so correct me if I wrong.

I am writing c# code and I have service class that contains many methods I wish to test. I am looking for simplicity and don't have the time right now to get into the real world of unit tests. Is there any tool that I can load dll, specify the class and then it will allow me test each method and explore the return value?

I am just looking for automatic tool, which allow me to test my code in the very low level.

Thanks.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "explore"? Manually, or in actual test cases?

Comment: How do you mean "automatic"? It's either a tool that helps you *manually* test some code, or it's an *automatic* test which runs functions and verifies their outputs.

Comment: @Jon Skeet: by explore I mean something similar to the watch from visual studio.

Comment: @Naor: Any reason you can't just start a tiny console app which sets up the service, hit a break point and then use the Immediate window?

Comment: @Tim Rogers: I am looking fot automatic test which allow me to select a method and run it. The same way you run web service in visual studio (the blue screen with all the web service's methods).

Comment: @Jon Skeet: I can use tiny console application but then I will not be able to watch complex return values. This will require me to write convertors that display each return value type and this is a new development I don't have time for. I don't want to use brakepoint because the user who tests it don't have enough knowledgh with visual studio.

Comment: @Naor: It sounds like there are a lot of best practices you don't have time for. Are you sure you're going about things the right way for the long term? Short term hacks are almost always a bad idea in the long run...

Comment: @Jon Skeet: I am looking for something for the sort run. Something that will allow other test my code while I still working on it.

Comment: I don't know of anything that fits your requirements, I'm afraid. I would personally spend the time getting into testing properly instead...

Comment: @Jon Skeet: I wish I had a time. I have alredy passed the deadline and there are other priorities then unit tests. I know that if I will find something like I ask things will be easier here.

Answer (score 5):

NUnit is a great testing framework for .NET, or the testing framework that comes built into Visual Studio is also pretty good.

Have a look at the NUnit quick start guide here http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=quickStart&r=2.2.10

One point, no tool exists to my knowledge that does what you ask, you have to write the tests yourself

Comment: I recommend NUnit as well. Sharp Architecture uses it.

Comment: I would also recommend NCrunch (http://www.ncrunch.net/) in conjunction with unit testing and TDD.

Answer (score 2):

[Micorosoft Pex](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/pex/)  is a Visual Studio add-in for testing .NET Framework applications, it automatically generates test suites with high code coverage. Right from the Visual Studio code editor, Pex finds interesting input-output values of your methods, which you can save as a small test suite with high code coverage.

HTH

Answer (score 1):

Typemock's isolator has a feature which invokes unit-tests for your methods absolutely autonomously, it wont take your time as a developer.
It can generate tests both on Nunit and Mstest unit-testing frameworks.